# Select the first value that meets a condition in another column within a window

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a case where I need to select the first value on one column based on a filter condition within another column and this should be done in a window function (over) with `mapping_strategy='join'`. Then I will use that value, which is a list to do SET DIFFERENCE on both of the list columns.

Here is the example:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'key': ['id1','id1', 'id1'],
    'list_main': [['a','b','c','d','e']]*3,
    "list_per_item":[['a','b'], ['a','b','c','d'], ['a','b','c']],
    'found': [False, False, True]
})
print(df)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────┐
│ key ┆ list_main         ┆ list_per_item     ┆ found │
│ --- ┆ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ list[str]         ┆ list[str]         ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════╡
│ id1 ┆ ["a", "b", … "e"] ┆ ["a", "b"]        ┆ false │
│ id1 ┆ ["a", "b", … "e"] ┆ ["a", "b", … "d"] ┆ false │
│ id1 ┆ ["a", "b", … "e"] ┆ ["a", "b", "c"]   ┆ true  │
└─────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────┘
```

So I have one way that will work but I wanted to see if there is a better way, take first row in over:

```
value = pl.col('list_per_item').first().over('key', mapping_strategy='join')
df.sort('found', descending=True).with_columns(
    pl.col('list_per_item').list.set_difference(value),
    pl.col('list_main').list.set_difference(value),
    value.alias('list_to_subtract') # In my own code I don't keep this.
)

shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────────────┬───────┬──────────────────┐
│ key ┆ list_main  ┆ list_per_item ┆ found ┆ list_to_subtract │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---              │
│ str ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[str]     ┆ bool  ┆ list[str]        │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╪══════════════════╡
│ id1 ┆ ["e", "d"] ┆ []            ┆ true  ┆ ["a", "b", "c"]  │
│ id1 ┆ ["e", "d"] ┆ []            ┆ false ┆ ["a", "b", "c"]  │
│ id1 ┆ ["e", "d"] ┆ ["d"]         ┆ false ┆ ["a", "b", "c"]  │
└─────┴────────────┴───────────────┴───────┴──────────────────┘
```

Other things I tried, filtering the df and then joining it back, however this will run OOM with en example where I create 300k rows. Does anyone notice a more efficient way of doing this with the expressions?

Comment: I guess this work now, when I tried it yesterday it didn't allow me to do it it gave a not implemented error :S, maybe I had my parenthesis wrong:

`df.with_columns(
    pl.col('list_per_item').filter(pl.col('found')).first().over('key', mapping_strategy='join').alias('found_list')
)`

Comment: `.first().over()`with lists was just fixed. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11749 (If that's why you have the mapping_strategy.)

Comment: It's not yet in .0.19.10 but I will try to build it locally and see if I can remove the mapping strategy. I did not even know this was a bug, I thought it was expected behaviour

Comment: That fix was part of `0.19.9` - With regards to your actual question, is the `.filter().first()` in your comment the actual answer? So this is solved?

Comment: Ah, I will run some checks then to see if I can do without mapping strategy, but yes it's solved now.